# Selected items in DataGridViewComboBoxColumn always retrieve the first value

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcombobox, datagridviewcomboboxcolumn

Assume the data I have are `'valuenumber1'`, `'valuenumber2'`, `'valuenumber3'`.

I have a problem where when `'valuenumber2'` or `'valuenumber3'` is selected, the next row will be created but the previous row (having `'valuenumber2'` or `'valuenumber3'`) will change to `'valuenumber1'` and this leads to all created rows having value of only `'valuenumber1'`.

For example (Please excuse my picture editing):

[image]

Example of my codes:

> Note: 'cto' is Connection to Oracle

```
public class Result
{
    public Result()
    {
        ds = new DataSet();
    }

    private DataSet ds;
    public List<ComboItems> LCI { get; set; }

    public DataSet ResultDataSet
    {
        get
        {
            return ds;
        }
        set
        {
            ds = value;
        } 
    }        
}

public class ComboItems
{
    public string objectName { get; set; }
    public string objectID { get; set; }

    public ComboItems(){}

    public ComboItems(string objectName, string objectID): this()
    {
        this.objectName = objectName;
        this.objectID = objectID;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return objectName;
    }
}

public Result GetList()
{
        Result rs = new Result();

        string commandText = "SELECT CUST_CODE, CUST_NAME FROM MAIN_CUSTOMER";
        rs.ResultDataSet = cto.Select(commandText);

        int maxRow = rs.ResultDataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count;

        List<ComboItems> lci = new List<ComboItems>();

        for (int tblrow = 0; tblrow < maxRow; tblrow++)
        {
            ComboItems ci = new ComboItems();
            ci.objectID = rs.ResultDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[tblrow]["CUST_CODE"].ToString();
            ci.objectName = rs.ResultDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[tblrow]["CUST_NAME"].ToString();

            lci.Add(ci);
        }
        rs.LCI = lci;
        return rs;
}

private void loadProjectList()
{
        Result rs = GetList();

        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cmb = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        cmb.HeaderText = "Select Data";
        cmb.Name = "cmb";
        cmb.MaxDropDownItems = 4;

        foreach (ComboItems ci in rs.LCI)
        {
            cmb.Items.Add(ci);
        }

        dgvList.Columns.Add(cmb);

        this.dgvList.EditingControlShowing +=
            new DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventHandler(dgvList_EditingControlShowing);
}
```

I tried to use EditingControlShowing event handler but it does not work:

```
private void dgvList_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox cmb = e.Control as ComboBox;
    if (cmb != null)
         cmb.SelectedIndex = -1;
}
```

As ComboBox in datagridview does not have SelectedIndex, is there other solutions which I am not aware of i.e by using other event handler?

Comment: The behavior can not be reproduced in a fully unbound `DataGridview`. But if you have a datagridview with some bound columns and some unbound columns, unbound columns will lost their values. Consider posting a [MCVE].

Comment: Copy the following code and paste it in `Load` event of a clean form, run the application and see the result:    `var dgv = new DataGridView();
    dgv.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    var combo = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
    combo.Items.AddRange(new string[] { "1", "2", "3" });
    combo.HeaderText = "Combo";
    dgv.Columns.Add(combo);
    this.Controls.Add(dgv);
    dgv.BringToFront();`

Comment: That's why I said a [MCVE] is required. How could we know in which context you are doing your tests? How could we know what's the result of `BusinessLayer.GetList();`? Also it's not clear how your `DataGridView` has been set up.

Comment: You should be able to reproduce the problem using a really simple code like what I shared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you want to load your combo items that way.  Rather, bind that column to the list you retrieve form you DB.  Something like this:

```
private void loadProjectList()
{
    Result rs = GetList();

    DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cmb = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
    cmb.HeaderText = "Select Data";
    cmb.Name = "cmb";
    cmb.MaxDropDownItems = 4;
    cmb.DataSource = rs.LCI;
    cmb.DisplayMember = "objectName";
    cmb.ValueMember = "objectID";

    dgvList.Columns.Add(cmb);
}
```